# Swift ios sometimes setNavigationBarHidden is ignored when i push to the VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am hiding y navigation bar for a specific view by calling `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` in `viewDidLoad`

But sometimes the navigation bar does not get hidden when I push to that VC. I have no idea whats causing this so it makes it really hard to debug. It happens once every 20 times or so..

So any ideas why `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` sometimes does not work?

Worth mentioning: When I exit the VC I show the navigation bar again by:

```
func backBtnDidToucH() {
popViewcontroller...
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

I dont do it in viewwilldissapear since the animation does not look as good as when I do it in the function above

Comment: try hiding in `viewwillappear` and showing in `viewwilldiappear`

Comment: @Vinodh same thing, sometimes it does not get hidden : /